# .Net Realms Assertion failed: !realm.is_in_transaction() turn on backtrace

Tags: .net, realm

I'm using Realms on .Net and I get the error

`The active test run was aborted. Reason: Test host process crashed : D:\a\realm-dotnet\realm-dotnet\wrappers\realm-core\src\realm\object-store\impl\realm_coordinator.cpp:1160: [realm-core-13.23.4] Assertion failed: !realm.is_in_transaction() 12:03:26:319    <backtrace not supported on this platform>`

I get this error occasionally when running my test suite and I've tried to resolve this issue reviewing all my code with realms ensuring that everything that changes entries is within a `realm.Write` but this still occurs.

I mostly just want to get the backtrace to show. I'm using .Net 8 and realms version 11.6.1

Comment: The question is vague - we would need to see the code causing the crash to really be of any help. Please take a moment and review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)